# If I have nested a span tag inside H1 tag,Is it effect SEO

Tags: seo, html, local-seo, seo-audit, negative-seo

I have a site that give users all kind of services

so let's say I put a span tag inside my H1 tag and with js I will replace it every 3 sec

for example my h1 tag contains :

```
<h1>Best italian food in NY order now <span id="dyn_txt">pizza </span> </h1>
```

With js i will replace the inner text of the span with: pasta,bolognese...

Comment: Normally, I would tell you that formatting HTML such as span would be ignored, however, since you are doing JS stuff to change your header tag, I would say this is unwise. I would assume that the first value you set is all the search engines will see providing they can see the value at all.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer.
I do it for the user experience not to cheat the SEO.
I just wont the user to know he can order all kind of stuff that i have on the top due to the site structure.
I need to know if it can make damage to my seo or maybe get punished from google.Many Thanks

Comment: I will let someone more expert in JS and dynamic sites answer this question. I would at least do a Fetch as Google in the Webmaster Tools and see if there are any immediate issues. I rather suspect you will be okay- it just will take only the first value if the fetch works as expected.

Comment: Are saying the "pizza" will be ignored?

Comment: I suspect that Pizza would be what your page is weighted for.

Comment: `I would tell you that formatting HTML such as span would be ignored` Since when does span get annoyed? SPAN rocks and is a good practice.

Comment: Google understands most changes in the DOM. Injecting text is rather common, Google is likely to count the entire header as one, for example `your header title + keyword + keyword + keyword + keyword` therefor your h1 will become long and diluted, and weighted less.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If you're having to dynamically change the text to explain to a visitor what food they can order then there are more fundamental issues with your website than what your question asks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are doing the JS.  Google wont index dynamic content (usually) so if you are pulling these items from a db or remote server then you could have an issue. If you are just rotating through a finite array of items by alternating css classes and those are in the static html but hidden (a jquery approach) then the site should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en#design_and_content_guidelines

And it states "Avoid tricks intended to improve search engine rankings.". It also suggests you make the site primarily for users. I'm not sure if users want to see text change every three seconds.

Also, the contents of the H1 tag are very important to search engines and with luck you'll get listed in search engines for pizza instead of bolongese or pasta. because pizza is what the search engine bots can read. I personally would not use any other tags inside the H1 tag.

If you must provide word animation on your site, you should make images with those words in them to help users understand the meaning. For example, for pizza, show a box of pizza, and for pasta, show spaghetti. Make a carousel formatted design. My bank's website uses a carousel based design where large images change every few seconds with the option to choose an image and to pause the changes:

```
http://pcfinancial.ca/
```